# Delphi Android service crash when add FMX.types declaration

Tags: delphi, firemonkey

I have Delphi 11 Alexandria, and I've recreated the simple demo to ["make an Android Service"](http://delphi.org/2015/09/minimalistic-android-service-with-delphi-10-seattle/).

It works fine when I run it on my Android phone, so now I want to add more complexity to the service by adding a `TTimer` component to the `TDataModule`, but when I add the `TTimer` then the app crashes when started.

Then I remove the `TTimer` component from the `TDataModule` and run again, but the app crashes again.

If I then remove the declaration of `FMX.Types` from the service (it was added when I put the `TTimer` on the `TDataModule`), then the app run fine again.

Why is it not possible to add `FMX.Types` into an Android service?

Is it not possible to use `TTimer` in an Android service?

Comment: This is known issue https://quality.embarcadero.com/browse/RSP-17857 Adding FMX.Types

Comment: The link is broken

Comment: Not for me... just tried it again... Maybe you have problems with logging in?

Comment: Link also works for me. I've been struggling with services with a few weeks now and now I finally understand why I was struggling. A bug from 2017 still not fixed after 4 years...

Comment: I can access the ticket. Still an unresolved issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @DalijaPrasnikar mentioned in a comment, this is a known bug:

[RSP-17857: Android service applications crash if FMX.Types unit is included](https://quality.embarcadero.com/browse/RSP-17857)

The `FMX.Types` unit doesn't work in a service, as its initialization is trying to access a `nil` pointer at runtime (specifically, a global named `DelphiActivity`, which is not set for a service, only for an app).

To use a timer in a service, try this workaround code:

https://github.com/DelphiWorlds/KastriFree/blob/master/Demos/AndroidLocation/Common/LS.AndroidTimer.pas